# Using ARM template to activate MSI for an azure VM

Tags: azure, azure-managed-identity

As mentioned in the document. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-service-identity/qs-configure-template-windows-vm

MSI is not activated by just using

```html
"identity": { 
    "type": "systemAssigned"
},
```

We had to use vm extensions as well in Step (4) but its marked as optional in the document. Could someone help validate this ?

Answer (score 0):

The VM extension is now an optional step, as we support retrieving tokens via the Azure Instance Metadata endpoint.

Simply setting identity type to "SystemAssigned" is sufficient. :)